# Changing the speed for a jquery scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [simplyScroll v2](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/), I have 2 scrolling blocks on my home page, but they are scrolling with the same speed, I want to change the speed for this block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     (function($) {
          $(function() {                    
              $("#scrollerv").simplyScroll({orientation:'vertical',customClass:'vert'});
          });
     })(jQuery);
</script>
```

How I can manage that? Without touching the JS files.
Thx for the help!

Comment: Try with speed option in simplyScroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/#config) of the plugin:

> speed, default: 1, Number of pixels moved per frame, in 'loop' mode must be divisible by total width of scroller

So your code needs to be:

```
$("#scrollerv").simplyScroll({
    orientation: 'vertical',
    customClass: 'vert',
    speed: 2 // increase to make faster
});
```

Comment: so, the minimum speed, will be 1?
1px per frame? I changed to 1 and I still think is to fast, need a bit slower.

Comment: @ValeriCrudu I would assume `1` is the minimum value (and therefore slowest) if you need slower you would have to drop the framerate parameter.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah I understood that, anyways, thx for the help.. ;)